# Disabling or Limiting Tor Functionality in Brave Browser on macOS

Tags: macos, hosts-file, tor, brave, safe-browsing

I'm seeking guidance on how to disable or limit the Tor functionality within the Brave browser on my macOS system. While I appreciate the privacy aspects that Tor integration provides, I have specific requirements that necessitate disabling this feature.

I maintain a list of forbidden websites blocked by my host files, using https://github.com/StevenBlack/hosts as a reference. This method works for regular Brave or other browsers, such as Chrome. Unfortunately, it does **not** work for Brave when using Tor in private windows.

My objective is to enforce these restrictions on the Tor browser. If that's not possible, I would like to entirely disable or remove the Tor functionality from Brave. Alternatively, hiding or disabling the option in the browser interface, or at least the keyboard shortcut, would be sufficient.

I have attempted the following. There is this path on my macOS:

```
/Users/pedro/Library/Application Support/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/tor/data
```

I tried fiddling with the `torrc` file and added:

```
MapAddress *.twitter.com 127.0.0.1
```

However, this does **not** work. I can still access twitter on Tor Browser.

What do you suggest?

-- UPDATE

[@harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc) suggested disabling Tor browser on the brave's extensions. Unfortunately, this option does not seem to exist:

[image]

But, after searching for it, I found this and successfully disable it:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable Tor in Brave by navigating to
`brave://settings/extensions` and then Toggle Tor off.

(I don't know how to do that for specific sites.)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Unfortunately, I believe that executing your suggestion is not possible. See my updated question. I inserted a print screen.